# Javascript function stops being recognized

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, dom-events

I'm having a problem with the following code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hangman</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        gallows = new Array("--------\n|      |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
        "--------\n|      O\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
        "--------\n|      O\n|      |\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|      |\n|\n|\n=====",
        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|      |\n|     /\n|\n=====",
        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|      |\n|     / \\\n|\n=====");

        guessChoices = new Array("JavaScript", "Navigator", "LiveConnect", "LiveWire");

        guessed = [];

        function startAgain()
        {
            guesses = 0;
            max = gallows.length - 1;
            //guessed = " ";
            len = guessChoices.length - 1;
            toGuess = guessChoices[Math.round(len*Math.random())].toUpperCase();
            displayHangman();
            displayToGuess();
            displayGuessed();
        }

        function stayAway()
        {
            document.game.elements[3].focus();
            alert("Don't mess with this form element!");
        }

        function displayHangman()
        {
            document.game.status.value=gallows[guesses];
        }

        function displayToGuess()
        {
            pattern = "";

            for(i=0;i<toGuess.length;++i)
            {
                if(guessed.indexOf(toGuess.charAt(i)) != -1)
                    pattern += (toGuess.charAt(i)+" ");
                else pattern += "_ ";
            }

            document.game.toGuess.value=pattern;
        }

        function displayGuessed(s)
        {

            result="";

            for(i in s)
            {
                guess=s[i];
                result += guess;
            }

            document.game.guessed.value=result;

            //document.game.guessed.value=guessed;
        }

        function badGuess(s)
        {
            if(toGuess.indexOf(s) == -1) return true;
            return false;
        }

        function winner()
        {
            for(i=0;i<toGuess.length;++i)
            {
                if(guessed.indexOf(toGuess.charAt(i)) == -1) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function guess(s)
        {
            if(guessed.indexOf(s) == -1) guessed.push(s);
            if(badGuess(s)) ++guesses;
            displayHangman();
            displayToGuess();
            displayGuessed(guessed);
            if(guesses >= max)
            {
                alert("You're dead. The word you missed was "+toGuess+".");
                startAgain();
            }
            if(winner()) 
            {
                alert("You won!");
                startAgain();
            }
        }
        // -->
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hangman</h1>
            <form name="game">
                <pre>
                    <textarea name="status" rows="7" cols="16" onfocus="stayAway();"></textarea>
                </pre>

                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="toGuess" onfocus="stayAway();"> Word to guess<br>
                    <input type="text" name="guessed" onfocus="stayAway();"> Letters guessed so far<br>
                </p>

                <p>Enter your next guess.</p>

                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="input" size=1 value="">
                    <input type = "button" value = "guess" onclick = "guess(game.input.value); game.input.value = '';">
                </p>

                <input type="button" name="restart" value="---- Start Again ----" onclick="startAgain();">

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    <!--
                    startAgain();
                    // -->
                </script>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

After I click the game.guess button, the first time around, I get the expected output... game.input clears and guessed is displayed. However, the second time I click the guess button with a different value, I receive the error:

```
guess is not a function
|   onclick()
|   event = click clientX=77, clientY=33

guess(game.input.value)                 onclick(line 2)
```

And I honestly can't figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

(I got the bulk of this code from Mastering JavaScript, Premium Edition, by James Jaworski)

Comment: i hope you didnt pay too much...

Comment: This is why you should always define your variables. And that's actually recommended by a book? Don't use that book anymore.

Comment: Run the hell away from that book.  It looks about 10 years out dated.

Comment: talk about paste everything and let others figure it out. you can start by stripping down your code

Comment: I wanted to strip it down, but I'm honestly so new to javascript that I couldn't figure out which parts were relevant... so I decided to put it all up.

Comment: @gfppaste Don't let these trolls upset you. Having said that, you can generally remove "commented" lines, and omit libraries that you're not actually using (such as your jQuery import). All in all though, it's clear that this is a decent question and that you are trying to figure out the answer yourself.

In the future, try commenting out large parts of your code, and  introduce them again one small part at a time until you start to see the problem. This focuses your attention the are of the code that's causing the issue.

Comment: @aaaidan I wasn't trolling.  I legitimately think that he should learn from a different book.

Comment: @Corbin, Sorry I guess i was talking more about the first comment, and Joseph's comment.

Comment: I can't vouch for or against the book in question, but I hear great things about http://www.codecademy.com/

Comment: I've heard it's infinitely better than w3schools... I'm trying to learn javascript in about 8 hours because I'm at a hackathon and decided to turn my java application into a webapp, so I'm kind of taking any code that looks simple right now haha.

Comment: Yeah. W3Schools is in dire need of ... reinventing itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on these lines:

```
guess=s[i];
result += guess;
```

This way you are changing the context of `guess`. If you change this line to

```
result += s[i];
```

Your error will go away.
You are conflicting your function with using same name for a variable.
Remember to define your variables using `var` keyword and avoid such confusion.

1 - use anonymous functions where possible

2 - declare and use local variables

To avoid conflicts.

Comment: I remember when I was learning javascript, I found it kinda counter intuitive that declaring "var" _contains_ the variable within the current scope, whereas omitting the keyword declares the variable in the global scope. Nota bene!

Answer (score 0):

In your function `displayGuessed()`, you are setting the variable `guess` (which is a function) to the the guessed letters.

You can fix this by defining your function's `guess` variable (making it distinct from the function) using the "var" keyword:

```
function displayGuessed(s) 
{
    var guess;
    result="";

    for(i in s)
    {
        guess=s[i];
        result += guess;
    }
    document.game.guessed.value=result;
}
```

Tip: I found this bug easily by using the Firebug plugin for firefox, which lets you step through javascript code line by line, to see where things are going wrong.